# Help finding poem about a red tide coming in which mentions "memory"

Tags: poetry, identification-request

I'm trying to find a poem. I thought it was a Mary Oliver poem, but I can't find it when searching the few words I know along with her name.

The poem talks about a red tide coming in. There is a part where the poem mentions "memory".

I know I haven't given much information but does anyone know of a poem like this?

Comment: Hi, I see that you question has been migrated and this stack’s story-identification tag has been added. It would be very helpful, and improve your question’s reception if you click through on that tag and find the information page. There is a lot of advice and a checklist there for information to include, the more you can tell us the better chance of getting a successful ID. Anyway, welcome to LitSE, please take the time to make the [tour] and visit the [help] too.